# Inherit classes in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class and two classes derivated of this principal class:

```
abstract class MainClass
{
    public void DoSomething() {
        if(isEdit())
            Edit();
        else if(isNew())
            New();
        else if(isDelete())
            Delete();
        else if(isSearch())
            Search();
        else if(isExit())
            Exit();
    }

    public abstract void Edit();
    public abstract void New();
    public abstract void Delete();
    public abstract void Search();
    public abstract void Exit();
}

abstract class FirstClass : MainClass
{
    public abstract void Edit();
    public abstract void New();
    public abstract void Delete();
}


abstract class SecondClass : MainClass
{
    public abstract void Search();
    public abstract void Exit();
}
```

When you need to extend from FirstClass `Edit()`, `New()` and `Delete()` must be declared, and methods `Search()` and `Exit()` can be declared but should not be mandatory. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem. Read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the optional methods as [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)s:

```
abstract class FirstClass : MainClass
{
    public override void Search(){}
    public override void Exit(){}
}
```

Since they are *implemented* in `MainClass`, you don't need to implement in any inheriting class, but if you *want* to, you can [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) them.

Note that you do not need to redeclare `Edit`, `New` and `Delete` again - they are already inherited by `FirstClass` and will need to be implemented by any non-abstract inheritor of it.

Comment: Well, you were just marginally faster. :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Yes... Well noted :)

Comment: Not quite, since Search() and Exit() are already defined in the MainClass, which is the baseclass for Firstclass.  So, you need to override them. :)

Comment: You are `hiding` Edt/New/Delete. Your methods wont be called from a MainClass reference.

Comment: What Henk Holterman says is correct; you'll get a compiler warning which states that you're applying method hiding.

Comment: @Oded oops - your first edit was correct :) methods should be overriden

Comment: You are still `hiding` Search and Exit and this won't compile. Hiding an abstract method is an Error.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels - True enough. Needed a couple of minutes with the compiler to get it right.

Answer (score 3):

> When you need to extend from FirstClass Edit(), New() and Delete() must be declared, and methods Search() and Exit() can be declared but should not be mandatory.

That is possible:

```
abstract class FirstClass : MainClass
{
    //public abstract void Edit();
    //public abstract void New();
    //public abstract void Delete();

    public override void Search()  { }
    public override void Exit()    { }
}
```

Edit(), New() and Delete() are already declared as abstract (must override) in the MainClass so FirstClass should leave them alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the non-mandatory methods that have been declared in `MainClass` which is the baseclass for `FirstClass`, and provide default functionality for it:

```
abstract class FirstClass : MainClass
{            
    public override  void Search(){}
    public override  void Exit() {}
}
```

The mandatory methods should not be declared in `FirstClass`, since they're already declared as abstract in the `MainClass`.  They remain abstract in `FirstClass`

Answer (score 0):

Override methods which could be optionally declared in child classes (other methods will be inherited from `MainClass` and stay abstract):

```
abstract class FirstClass : MainClass
{  
    public override void Search() { /* default implementation */ }
    public override void Exit() { /* default implementation */  }
}
```

Then

```
class ThirdClass : FirstClass
{ 
    // Must implement abstract methods
    public override void Edit() { }
    public override void New() { }
    public override void Delete() { }

    // Optionally override 
    public override void Exit() { /* custom implementation */  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The abstract keyword indicates that a method MUST be implemented by an inheriting class. The virtual keyword indicates that it MAY be implemented.

Mark Save() and Exit() as virtual and provide a default (possibly empty) implementation of them.

Comment: There is no requirement that an inheriting class implement an abstract method. The inheriting class could itself be abstract.